# Camel Failing Core Test Cases

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot, apache-camel

I’ve been trying to build a Camel jetty9 project using the ‘mvn clean install’ command.

(Specifically `mvn clean install -pl :camel-jetty9 -am -e`)

When I run the command, it proceeds to build and start run test cases. However, some test cases fail; see below.

### Output

```
**[ERROR]** org.apache.camel.component.file.FileConsumerExcludeNameTest.testExludePreAndPostfixes(org.apache.camel.component.file.FileConsumerExcludeNameTest)
**[ERROR]**   Run 1: FileConsumerExcludeNameTest>TestSupport.runBare:58->testExludePreAndPostfixes:36 mock://result Message with body Reports1 was expected but not found in [Reports2, Reports3]
**[ERROR]**   Run 2: FileConsumerExcludeNameTest>TestSupport.runBare:58->testExludePreAndPostfixes:36 mock://result Message with body Reports1 was expected but not found in [Reports3]
**[ERROR]**   Run 3: FileConsumerExcludeNameTest>TestSupport.runBare:58->testExludePreAndPostfixes:36 mock://result Message with body Reports1 was expected but not found in [Reports2, Reports3]

**[ERROR]** org.apache.camel.impl.FileWatcherReloadStrategyTest.testUpdateExistingRoute(org.apache.camel.impl.FileWatcherReloadStrategyTest)
**[ERROR]**   Run 1: FileWatcherReloadStrategyTest>TestSupport.runBare:58->testUpdateExistingRoute:122 Should reload file within 20 seconds
**[ERROR]**   Run 2: FileWatcherReloadStrategyTest>TestSupport.runBare:58->testUpdateExistingRoute:122 Should reload file within 20 seconds
**[ERROR]**   Run 3: FileWatcherReloadStrategyTest>TestSupport.runBare:58->testUpdateExistingRoute:122 Should reload file within 20 seconds

**[ERROR]** org.apache.camel.impl.FileWatcherReloadStrategyTest.testUpdateXmlRoute(org.apache.camel.impl.FileWatcherReloadStrategyTest)
**[ERROR]**   Run 1: FileWatcherReloadStrategyTest>TestSupport.runBare:58->testUpdateXmlRoute:162 ▒ ConditionTimeout
**[ERROR]**   Run 2: FileWatcherReloadStrategyTest>TestSupport.runBare:58->testUpdateXmlRoute:180 Should reload file within 20 seconds
**[ERROR]**   Run 3: FileWatcherReloadStrategyTest>TestSupport.runBare:58->testUpdateXmlRoute:162 ▒ ConditionTimeout
```

### Repro

1. Clone the Camel repository from github
2. Enter the directory and checkout branch camel-2.22.1
3. Run `mvn clean install -pl :camel-jetty9 -am -e`

### Environment

- Windows 10
- jdk 1.8.0_181
- Maven 3.5.3
- Camel 2.22.1

### What I tried

I attempted different versions of Camel and jdk combinations to see if it was something concerning updates with Java; however according to the [Camel site](http://camel.apache.org/what-are-the-dependencies.html), everything past Camel 2.14 should work with my jdk, so I mostly tried different versions of Camel to see if there were any differences in output.

### My Questions

1. Are test cases required to create the jetty9 jar file?
2. Can I simply remove them?
3. Are these test cases supposed to pass for each release?
4. Is there a specific Maven or jdk version that pass these tests?
5. If necessary, what do I do to 'fix' them?

Thank you all in advance.

### Edit

I tried running the same process with Camel versions: 2.22.0, 2.21.0, and 2.20.0, and they all had the same issues. *However*, when I tried 2.19.0 and 2.19.5, it built successfully. Currently investigating.

Comment: Is there a specific reason you are trying to build the project yourself rather than adding a maven dependency? For example... https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.camel/camel-jetty9/2.22.0

Comment: We are trying to fork the project and modify it, then put the resulting built project into a private maven repository, from which we will pull.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I saw issues as well by running that command from the top-level camel pom directory.  I cd'd into the components directory and ran that same command and it was successful.  Alternatively, I also tested just by going into the components/camel-jetty9 directory and running "mvn clean install" and that was much quicker and passed but didn't build all the other components.  Either one of these might be enough.

EDIT: This was for the latest camel release, 2.22.1. JDK 1.8.0_131, Maven 3.5.0.